# Remove the outline from Bootstrap 5 accordion buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

When you check out the [Bootstrap 5 accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/) you'll see an outline. I want to remove it. I am not sure which element actually produces the outline, but I suspect it is the `button`. In any case I have tried to apply the following to all possible elements:

```css
.accordion-item, .accordion-item:focus, .accordion-item:active,
.accordion-header, .accordion-header:focus, .accordion-header:active,
.accordion-button, .accordion-button:focus, .accordion-button:active {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

Nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Here is a copy of the html code:

```html
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are lot of conditions in the css you are writing, you can keep it simple add another new class at the end of the element you want to outline none ? like thiz :

in css :
.outline-none { outline: none !important; }

add outline-none class in the end of your element

Comment: Thanks, but I even tried that. Does not work.

Comment: its not come from outline, it show box-show on focus  add this : ".accordion-button:focus {box-shadow: none;}"

Comment: Saved my day @SatishModha. If you post an answer I would happily accept it. Please add `!important`, it seems to be necessary.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To remove the shadow and blue border color...

```
.accordion-button:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.125);
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/tNl1EZtAKF)

Comment: Thanks very much, @Zim. I was struggling for 1/2 an hour to get rid of the border. Now to figure out how to make the caret (an svg) light-colored.

Comment: Does anyone know how to change the color instead of getting rid of it? I tried changing it with the code above but nothing happens.

Comment: I wouldn't apply it to just `:focus` because you can expand an item and click away from it but the selector `:focus` would still apply. Answer from @danialcodes would cover this.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed){
        box-shadow: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it will work:

```css
.accordion-item {
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I removed it. The class 'item' is my class i.e. it is my custom class.

```css
.accordion .item .accordion-header button{
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.accordion .item{
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<Accordion className="p-0"  alwaysOpen>
            <Accordion.Item eventKey="0" className="item">
              <Accordion.Header>Recent</Accordion.Header>
              <Accordion.Body className="d-flex flex-column">
                <div className="container d-flex flex-row">
                  <Groups />
                  <span className="mx-2">Events</span>
                </div>
                <div className="container d-flex flex-row">
                  <Groups />
                  <span className="mx-2">Events</span>
                </div>
                <div className="container d-flex flex-row">
                  <Groups />
                  <span className="mx-2">Events</span>
                </div>
                <div className="container d-flex flex-row">
                  <Groups />
                  <span className="mx-2">Events</span>
                </div>
                <div className="container d-flex flex-row">
                  <Groups />
                  <span className="mx-2">Events</span>
                </div>
              </Accordion.Body>
            </Accordion.Item>
            <Accordion.Item eventKey="1" className="item">
              <Accordion.Header>Groups</Accordion.Header>
              <Accordion.Body className="d-flex flex-column">
                <div className="container d-flex flex-row">
                  <Groups />
                  <span className="mx-2">Events</span>
                </div>
                <div className="container d-flex flex-row">
                  <Groups />
                  <span className="mx-2">Events</span>
                </div>
                <div className="container d-flex flex-row">
                  <Groups />
                  <span className="mx-2">Events</span>
                </div>
                <div className="container d-flex flex-row">
                  <Groups />
                  <span className="mx-2">Events</span>
                </div>
                <div className="container d-flex flex-row">
                  <Groups />
                  <span className="mx-2">Events</span>
                </div>
              </Accordion.Body>
            </Accordion.Item>
          </Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get the color change to white on both collapse and non collapse icon and also change the default border color:

```
.accordion-button:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.125);
}
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after{
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fff'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.accordion-button.collapsed::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fff'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
```